# Eclipse STS connecting to Tomcat

Tags: eclipse, tomcat

In Spring Tool Suite IDE, have added Tomcat server and started it. Console output says : INFO: Server startup in 19182 ms

But on trying url http://localhost:8080/, gives HTTP error 404
STS version - 3.6.2.

If server is started outside Eclipse, Tomcat homepage is accessible as usual.

Answer (score 0):

Try http://localhost:9087/ and see if that works. You may need to check your configurations for other port numbers, but 9087 should work.

Comment: But  netstat command gives TCP    0.0.0.0:8080. And on stopping tyhe server, the port is released. But for some reason, the server is not accessible. Also 9087 does not work. Any other solutions?

Answer (score 0):

Got it working!
Wile running tomcat in eclipse, not all files are copied in the new deployment location in the eclipse workspace. But after manually copying index.jsp and related images, the home page came.